# Is it possible to "freeze" a Pane expression?

Tags: graphics, pane, scrolling

My problem is the following: I want to clip a expression using Pane which works great. However, when navigating around the document, I often move the position of the expression inside Pane accidentally (scrolling with the mouse while the cursor is in the Pane area would do that). I wish there was an option to make sure the expression inside Pane does not move (Freezes). If tried manipulating the options Scrollbars, Enabled and ImageSizeAction among other to no avail. Below is a small snippet

```
Pane[Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 200], {100, 100}]
```

[image]

dragged by mistake with the mouse

[image]

Comment: If it is not the case that you _have to_ use `Pane` you can try `Panel`. For example, `Panel[Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 200], ImageSize -> {100, 100}, 
 Background -> White]`

Comment: thank @kglr. This actually works. I am not sure if i understand what is the difference between Panel and Pane. cheers